# URL Path Not Working

Tags: url, path, location

I'm trying to access a class inside of a jar using URLClassLoader.

Here is my hierarchy:

[image]

Why isn't:
`URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL(
                "http://rune-shadows.com/runeshadows.jar") });
        applet = (Applet) classLoader.loadClass("run/Run").newInstance();` 
working?

I tested the same code with a different jar with no folders, just a "Main" class in the root folder and it worked fine.  How is the path I have above incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Try including the www. at the start:

```
 "http://www.rune-shadows.com/runeshadows.jar"
```

Comment: how about including the extension?       classLoader.loadClass("run/Run.class").newInstance();

Comment: Doesn't matter either.  Like I said it can access my other jar when I put Main in the root directory.  It works without the .class ending.

Comment: hmm perhaps backslash is needed instead of forward because it's local addressing? "run\Run" ?

Comment: Not that either, causes a syntax error.  I also tried a . which also did't work.

Comment: Looks like the loadclass method takes the class name for it's parameter rather than a path to the file. [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String))